# LINQ version of sql query with multiple joins and group by

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL Query that I'm trying to rewrite as LINQ.  I've gotten through the left join aspects of it but I can't manage to combine it together with the group by stuff.

Here's the SQL Query that works and performs perfectly:

```
select count(c.ID) as NoteCount, count(s.StatusHistoryID) as ActionCount, p.DayGoal
from Collector_Profile p 
left join StatusHistory s on s.AppUserID = p.AppUserID 
and CONVERT(varchar(10), s.StatusDateTZ, 101) = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101)
left join Claim_Notes c on c.CollectorID = p.ID 
and CONVERT(varchar(10),c.PostDateTZ,101) = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101)
where p.ID = 1338
group by p.DayGoal
```

What I've got so far on the LINQ query is the following:

```
var query = from p in _context.Collector_Profile 
    join s in _context.StatusHistory on p.AppUserID equals s.AppUserID into gs
    join c in _context.Claim_Notes on p.ID equals c.CollectorID into gc
    from s in gs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from c in gc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.ID == CollectorID
    group p by p.DayGoal into grouped
```

But I don't know how to handle the date comparison truncating the date in that fashion, and I don't know how to select the results back from the query.  Can someone explain how to finish this up?

Comment: Are you just trying to compare the dates by year-month-day ignoring the hour, minutes, etc?

Comment: Yes, but I also need help in how you actually select the results from the grouped

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method to compare date part only.

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.StatusDateTZ)
```

Comment: What about the groupby section with the two tables, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I get the error DBFunctions does not contain a definition for TruncateTime.